# New website contact form is not working

Tags: php, contact-form

I'm new in web design. I'm currently building a new website for a company and my contact form is not working properly.
I've tested many times and used different php, but I'm still not getting any emails... The company that I am working with, they own a domain without hosting. I'm not really sure if that make it any different.

Here is my HTML and PHP. Please let me know if you see any problems! Thank you :)

HTML

```
<!-- Contact -->
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="cform" id="contact-form">
                            <div id="sendmessage">
                                 <p>Your message has been sent. Thank you!</p>
                            </div>
                            <form action="contact/contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" data-rule="maxlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 characters" />
                                <div class="validation"></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                                <div class="validation"></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="company">Company Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" id="company" data-rule="maxlen:4" data-msg="Please enter your company name" />
                                <div class="validation"></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" data-rule="maxlen:10" data-msg="Please enter your phone number" />
                                <div class="validation"></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="message">Message</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us"></textarea>
                                <div class="validation"></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="align-center">
                                <button type="submit" value="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-theme pull-left"><b>SEND MESSAGE</b></button>
                              </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

PHP

```
<?php
 if($_POST['submit'])
 {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $email_from = $name.'<'.$email.'>';

 $to="eewhyoh@gmail.com";
 $subject="True Label Contact Form";
 $body="      

         Name:
         $name     
         <br>
         Email:
         $email        
         <br>
         Company:
         $company
         <br>
         Phone Number:
         $phone:
         <br>
         Message:
         $message      

   ";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
 }
?>
```

Comment: Have you looked in the error logs? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: *"The company that I am working with, they own a domain without hosting. I'm not really sure if that make it any different."* - Sure does make a difference. No hosting=no `mail()`.

Comment: where is the mail sending part in your code ? mail() function maybe ?

Comment: Then what are you doing with $to,$subject, $body & $headers? if `mail()` is not present?

Comment: Where is your mail function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, it is very common to not name your inputs properly. You have no input named `submit` *(that I can see anyway)* therefore it will not get past the `if($_POST['submit'])`:

```
<div class="align-center">
    <input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" name="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-theme pull-left" />
</div>
```

Also, as mentioned by others, you have no `mail()`. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

```
// This portion you are missing.
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

To use it, at the very bottom of your enclosed code, you can do something similar to:

```
// mail will return true if sends, false if fail
echo (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))? 'Sent!' : 'Error, not sent.';
```

> **Addendum:**
>   *As noted by @Fred -ii-, "`mail()` should be made available to them, even if a hosting package isn't available. You can have `mail()` or other `SMTP` even if there is no hosting per se."*

Comment: even if this gets fixed, there's no `mail()` call anyways, so basically it'd be impossible for any email to get sent in the first place.

Comment: Yeah I just added that.

Comment: Not my downvote btw. Good catch on the submit name attribute though, however OP states: *"The company that I am working with, they own a domain without hosting. I'm not really sure if that make it any different."* - So, that alone is unclear whether `mail()` or other form of mailing is presently made available to them.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, I will give the OP as much info as I can about `mail()` in a standard setting and downvotes don't bother me. The problem is two-fold, and sure, the absence of the `mail()` is the main problem, but the addition of it in the code without fixing the naming would end in the same problem. Downvote away! :D

Comment: However, an added note to the OP would be good to let them know that `mail()` should be made available to them, even if a hosting package isn't available. You can have `mail()` or other SMTP even if there is no hosting per se. Just in case comments get deleted to that effect, as I stated under their question.

Comment: I will add an addendum!

Comment: How do I make this contact form work without a host?

Comment: Have you already modified your code with the additions mentioned?

Comment: *"How do I make this contact form work without a host?"* - You can contact the company who is the registrar for the domain name to see if they have `mail()` available for them only, or you can use SMTP through Google's Gmail or any other service with an API that you can use to pass credentials through. @eewhyoh for your present code, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Add an edit to what you have in your question to what you are currently using with the mods. Lets first check that what you have is actually correct. If it is, then you will need to find an alternative as suggested by Fred -ii-

Comment: @eewhyoh *"Yes. I added mail( ) and changed button to input, but it's still not working"* - Just because you added that function, doesn't mean you can use it. If `mail()` isn't available for you to use, then you can't use it; period.